# Where can I go for valid fonts for my game, The code is in Lua

Tags: lua, pong, edx

I am trying to build the pong game using the LUA code language. I keep receiving these errors, but I have no clue what to do or if I am doing anything right.

Error: Could not open file font.ttf. Does not exist

Error
TrueType Font loading error: FT_New_Face failed: 0x55(problem with font file?)

Comment: What game engine are you writing Lua script for?

Comment: The question is misleading. Do you want help with the error, or a place to get fonts from?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff This is for the Pong game.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I want help with the error as well as another website to get fonts if possible.